# purpose for the #ctl00_Menu_SkipLink

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, function, url

### what is the purpose for the code?

```
#ctl00_Menu_SkipLink
```

> 

### when i search something on http://google.com that time i saw this code on URL .

```
   **ctl00_Menu_SkipLink**
```

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%23**ctl00_Menu_SkipLink**&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=TBj3U775BcjtiALGiYHwCw#channel=sb&q=google&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&start=10

### I guess its for skip the link .

### anyone knows what is the purpose for that code can anyone explain to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#ctl00_Menu_SkipLink is an Id for a HTML tag 
automatically generated by .net compiler for a **web control**,
 most likely type hyperlink or linkbutton in his case, in a **asp.net page** with a **masterpage**